# Why is the preview in the assistant editor giving the wrong iphone model

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I currently have a new project in which I am trying out some online lessons. I am having alignment issues in the simulator and I am trying to resolve them. I noticed that in the  `Assistant editor -> Automatic > Preview` the iphone model displayed is wrong. Here is the picture

[image]

I have chosen iphone 6 for my project however iphone 4 inch is being displayed. I looked online and it states that iphone 6 is 4.7 inch. Why is the display in the preview wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: This is default view of 600*600 canvas for ios development in XCode 6. If you want you need an iPhone size then disable size classes and then you can have only iPhone size, but its better to use canvas as it will help you to display the UI in future upcoming devices of variable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In preview view, there is a "+" button at the bottom left corner, select it and it will display the available device options. Select iPhone 4.7 inch for the iPhone 6 preview.

Comment: Thats funny it changes the screen size in the preview however the text under it still reads 4 inches

Comment: Select the already shown preview option and delete it, then select the needed iPhone size from the bottom left "+" options. You can double click the preview screen to zoom in and zoom out to see all the previews added.